# git-hook hangs when launching docker compose

Tags: bash, git, docker-compose, githooks

I made this post-merge git hook for my Laravel app: it basically checks the changed files ad executes matching commands (run migrations, compile assets and so on)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
CHANGED_FILES="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

changed() {
    echo "$CHANGED_FILES" | grep -q "$1"
}


if [[ "$USER" == "root" || "$USER" == "ec2-user" ]]; then
    sudo chown -R www-data: htdocs
fi

if changed composer.lock; then
    docker-compose run --rm worker bash -c "composer install"
fi

if changed "migrations\|seeders"; then
    docker-compose run --rm worker php artisan migrate --force --seed
fi

if changed .blade.php$; then
    docker-compose run --rm worker php artisan view:clear
fi

if changed .php$; then
    docker-compose run --rm worker bash -c "php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear"
fi

if changed "yarn.lock$\|.js$\|.scss$"; then
    docker-compose run --rm node bash -c "yarn && yarn prod"
fi

if changed httpd.conf; then
    docker-compose up -d --force-recreate apache
fi

docker-compose restart worker

exit 0
```

if i launch the hook by hand `./.git-hook/post-merge` (it's in a non-conventional folder so the hook itself it's committed) it works
but when it's executed by git it always hangs after creating the container.
this only happens on AMI linux it works fine on my mac

output looks like this

```
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 21, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Decompressione degli oggetti in corso: 100% (13/13), 1.44 KiB | 490.00 KiB/s, fatto.
Da bitbucket.org:[my-private-repo]
   ec60a04..def0d31  master     -> origin/master
Aggiornamento di ec60a04..def0d31
Fast-forward
 .git-hooks/post-merge                         |  2 +-
 htdocs/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php | 25 ++++++++++++++++++++++---
 2 files changed, 23 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
++ git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD
+ CHANGED_FILES='.git-hooks/post-merge
htdocs/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php'
+ [[ ec2-user == \r\o\o\t ]]
+ [[ ec2-user == \e\c\2\-\u\s\e\r ]]
+ sudo chown -R www-data: htdocs
+ changed composer.lock
+ echo '.git-hooks/post-merge
htdocs/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php'
+ grep -q composer.lock
+ changed 'migrations\|seeders'
+ echo '.git-hooks/post-merge
htdocs/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php'
+ grep -q 'migrations\|seeders'
+ changed '.blade.php$'
+ echo '.git-hooks/post-merge
htdocs/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php'
+ grep -q '.blade.php$'
+ changed '.php$'
+ echo '.git-hooks/post-merge
htdocs/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php'
+ grep -q '.php$'
+ docker-compose run --rm worker bash -c 'php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear'
Creating www_worker_run ... done
```

`Creating www_worker_run ... done` is the last thing i see and then the output stops (I've waited a couple of minutes then given up)

thanks to @fredrik I have more info:
the command that hangs is this `docker-compose run --rm worker bash -c 'php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear'`
But i can run it just fine from the shell in 2.5 seconds

```
$ docker-compose run --rm worker bash -c 'php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear'
Creating www_worker_run ... done
Application cache cleared!
Route cache cleared!
```

Comment: That is not output that is printed by this script - so we cannot know where or why it hangs.

Comment: I've added the output and specified that the problem happens on AMI linux, not on my mac

Comment: But we still don't know where that is coming from. It is not standard git.

Comment: I don't understand what output should i give you, sorry for my poor understanding

Comment: Which of the commands your hook is running can produce that output? You can add `-x` to the first line in the script to make bash output all commands being executed.

Comment: i've added extended output this is the command that hangs `docker-compose run --rm worker bash -c 'php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear'`

Comment: So turn on debug logging for each of those commands and see what happens.

Comment: there is no verbose output for `docker-compose run` and the question is: what's different in me launching `./.git-hooks/post-merge` and in git doing the same stuff ?

Comment: When you launch you have an interactive terminal - git doesn't give it that. You can add debug output directly to the php commands, since it's seems to be one of those failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fredrik pointed out, the problem is that git doesn't have an interactive terminal and docker-compose command are failing

`-T` option is available just for that this.

from `docker run -h`:

```
-T Disable pseudo-tty allocation. By default `docker-compose run` allocates a TTY.
```